# Trouble running JavaFX with Maven project

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am a newbie to javafx and I am currently having a hard time trying to get HelloFX.java to run because I keep getting into this error:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

I have follow the tutorial from this guide: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction

I have install openjdk 13.0.1 and set JAVA_HOME as guided. Below is the snip of my terminal:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloFX</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>HelloFX</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>HelloFX</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this? If so, please let me know if you need me to provide more information. Thank you.

Comment: How do you run your project? Do you run `mvn clean javafx:run` or you run from your IDE?

Comment: How are you trying to run the program? from the IDE or CMD?

Comment: I think I ran from my IDE. How do I run mvn clean javafx:run? It would be nice if I can run it from my IDE

Comment: You can run from a terminal (to see that the process works fine), but you can also run from your IDE (selecting the Maven goals). The docs you linked have Maven sections for IntelliJ, NetBeans and Eclipse.

Comment: Remove the `\bin` from the value of environment variable `JAVA_HOME`. The value should be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1`

Comment: As the Maven log advises you: _re-run Maven with the -e switch_. The [edit] your post and add the entire stack trace.

Comment: Hey guys, after all the errors I got into, I followed this guide https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#next-steps and finally got it running. Thank you all.